# jQuery - combining variable with image src to replace image attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my script which is suppose to show the user a greeting message based on their local time. I got the script from another stack overflow answer, but am having trouble with replacing the image src. I get the following error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://localhost:8888/neil-wp/imgurl%20+%20second.jpg


$(document).ready(function () {
    datetoday = new Date(); // create new Date()
    timenow = datetoday.getTime(); // grabbing the time it is now
    datetoday.setTime(timenow); // setting the time now to datetoday variable
    hournow = datetoday.getHours();  //the hour it is
    imgselector = $('#greeting-img')
    imgpath = 'wp-content/themes/neil/img/'

    if (hournow >= 16.5) { // if it is after 4:30pm
        imgselector.attr("src","imgpath + goodevening.gif");
    }  
    else if (hournow >= 12) { // if it is after 12pm
        imgselector.attr("src","imgpath + goodafternoon.gif");
    } 
    else if (hournow >= 0) { // if it is after midnight
        imgselector.attr("src","imgpath + goodmorning.gif");
    }
});

// Wait for window load
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".greeting").delay(2000).fadeOut("200");
});
```

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="greeting">
    <div class="greeting-inner">
    <img id="greeting-img" src="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as `imgpath` is variable, use:

```
imgselector.attr("src",imgpath + "goodmorning.gif");
```